# Using loops with prompt()

Tags: javascript, loops, prompt

I'm trying to get five inputs from the user.

I know that calling functions in a loop (like in the below code) will crash, because all of the prompt()'s are getting called at the same time.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    prompt();
}
```

What solutions are there for this? I saw other snippets using a "timeout" with a set amount of time to wait between each function call, but would the code still work when the user can take as much time as they want to enter their prompt?

Answer (score 5):

> I know that calling functions in a loop (like in the below code) will crash, because all of the `prompt()`'s are getting called at the same time.

That't not the case here because `prompt` is a **blocking** function, just like `alert`. I.e. iteration (or rather code execution) only continues after the prompt windows was closed.

You could add all the values to an array like so:

```
var inputs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    inputs.push(prompt());
}
console.log(inputs);
```

---

Whether that's the best user experience is a different question...

Comment: Good answer. As a note, if I visit a website with 5 prompts in the same loop I close the browser as soon as possible. Imagine more than 5 prompts makes my mind crash.

Comment: I tried using your code and running it in repl.it 
However it gets hung up and frozen after the first input. Is there anything that I'm missing?

https://repl.it/BK26/1

Comment: @feedobesebison: Might be an issue with repl.it. Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/b3q666y2/1/

Answer (score 0):

No need for a timeout, the prompt will wait for user input (ok, cancel) before the rest of the code executes, meaning that the next prompt will come after clicking ok. The timeout is only usefull so that people do not accidentally press twice ok in a row and see the prompt appear.